# Уникальность имени контроллера в Angular + ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

Если мы регистрируем контроллер в модуле

```
angular.module('app.module1').controller('thisNameController', controller)
function controller(){}
```

и получаем к нему доступ через

```
angular.module('app.module1').config(configLoad)
...
.state{
    controller: 'thisNameController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
}
```

то имя контроллера должно быть уникально в пределах этого модуля или всего приложения?
Например, могут ли в других модулях быть контроллеры с таким же именем или вызовется тот, который будут зарегистрирован последним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уникальность имени должна быть на уровне **всего приложения**.

В противном случае будет использовано последнее определение.

Единственный случай, когда выполнятся несколько одноименных функций - это директивы.

Можно иметь несколько директив с одинаковым именем и все они независимы друг от друга. Но к модулям это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Не очень логично, но спасибо за ответ. Будем знать!

Comment: @mistbow, не, почему, с контролерами/сервисами и т.д. все просто - в итоге просто нет модулей, все находится в одном самом главном модуле, в который все подключается. С директивами, да, весь неочевидно все